# possibly invalid XHTML from a standard Haskell library?

Tags: html, haskell, xhtml

I'm trying to fix a problem with a program that generates XHTML using Haskell from UTF-8 text. The program takes strings of that text and should produce valid XHTML entities but doesn't. I'm importing Text.XHtml.Transitional, and use the functions href and identifier to generate URIs and ID attributes from UTF-8 strings. Using the Haskell interpreter we can see:

```
Prelude Text.XHtml.Transitional> href "äöü"
href="&#228;&#246;&#252;"
```

This is fine and a valid XHTML URI. However,

```
Prelude Text.XHtml.Transitional> identifier "äöü"
id="&#228;&#246;&#252;"
```

is not, according to the spec which doesn't allow '&', '#', and ';' characters.
So, it appears the Text.XHtml.Transitional lib is buggy. Moreover, I think even the XHMTL is bad because it doesn't give both a 1:1 mapping from UTF-8 in attributes and one that is identical to the mapping used for URIs.

As I'm new to Haskell, I might have made a mistake somewhere. Also, I know that HTML5 relaxes those attribute restrictions. But that's not dominating atm. Is the library buggy? If so, which mapping should replace the given one?

See also [Xhtml Invalid Characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471829/xhtml-invalid-characters)

Comment: OK. I want to give a ready solution to them. What 1:1 mapping can I use? Is there already a solution in another language?

Comment: If it's invalid, it would be because the `ä`, ö` and `ü` aren't valid as ID characters (I don't know whether they are or not), not because `&`, `#` and `;` are invalid, surely?

Comment: Yes, I presupposed that UTF-8 is invalid as ID. But &, #, ; are as well, so the normal URI escape mechanism is not sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

[Plenty of non-ascii unicode characters are valid in IDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar) (see the `Name` production), including your accented letters.

Note that [the production applies after normalisation](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize).

i.e. `&`, `#` and `;` may not appear in an ID, but in your example they *don't* appear in the ID --- the ID is `äöü`. This has then been encoded as `&#228;&#246;&#252;`, presumably to survive being output as US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1.

So I don't think it's a bug in the library.